# Syntax highlighting of unsupported language in WebStorm with TextMate bundle

Tags: webstorm, velocity, jetbrains-ide, textmatebundles

The usual answer to this question is, "download and add a suitable TextMate bundle." I have done that.

I'm working in WebStorm on a React project using GraphQL. It has a lot of `.vtl` (Velocity Template Language) files that do not have syntax highlighting. I found out that I can add a TextMate bundle for VTL in order to get highlighting. I got this bundle from https://github.com/textmate/java-velocity.tmbundle. After adding it to WebStorm, there still isn't an appropriate file type, and `.vtl` files still don't have syntax highlighting.

So, I tried to create a new custom file type, manually supplying lists of keywords to highlight, which make the code slightly more readable. However, every `.vtl` file is now entirely marked with squiggly red, saying, "Unexpected tokens." I just wanted keyword highlighting, not incorrect assumptions about grammar.

Is this a problem with WebStorm, the bundle, or me? How can I get some basic syntax highlighting specifically for `.vtl` files?

Note that the TextMate plugin is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle only provides highlighting for `*.vm` files. Please check if the issue persists if you open `java-velocity.tmbundle\Syntaxes\Velocity.tmLanguage` file in some text editor and add `vtl` to the list of supported extensions:

```
<key>fileTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>vm</string>
        <string>vtl</string>
    </array>
```

and re-start the IDE?
Note that you need to remove your custom file type to get the extension recognized

Comment: Thank you! That's the reason it didn't apply to `*.vtl` files. Unfortunately, it turns out the syntax highlighting is incomplete and not reliable, so I'll have to try to figure out why my custom file type causes "unexpected tokens" now.

Comment: Nevermind, the bundle works fine, I just didn't delete the custom file type correctly. Thanks again.